# Visual studio debugger getting data tip

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am using a VS 2017. a "Debugger, Getting a datatip text" window keep poping up when a project being run.

There is no use for data tips in the typescript files in my project. Is it possible to prevent that window poping up specifically in typescript files?

It gets really frustrating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
```

and uncheck the option 'Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls'

Hope this helps you